# What's the meaning of "that said"? Under what contexts can we use it?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

As title said, I'm confused by the meaning of "that said". I tried to google it, but I failed find a clear and convincing definition.

Comment: This can be answered by using a dictionary. [That said](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/that%2Bsaid___1)

Comment: Hi there! Thx for the question!

Answer (score 9):

The phrase 'that said' is often used at the beginning of a sentence as an informal 'however'. Like 'however', it indicates that the sentence it starts presents the opposite view to that of the previous sentence.

Answer (score 7):

"that said" = "having said that" has the easy meaning - after you/someone said or stated something. It is usually used when you want to add something to what was mentioned before (and you usually agree with what was said).

> This phone is expensive. That said, [I want to say that] the quality is really good.